# All the team project collections on this server already exist (TFS plugin for WebStorm)

Tags: plugins, tfs, azure-devops, webstorm

I am using the TFS integration plugin from WebStorm.

When connecting to our TFS server using a personal access token and alternate user account, I am getting a message saying

> All the team project collections on this server already exist

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify whether you are using VSTS or TFS on-premise? Could you share a screenshot of your setting?

Comment: Can you provide detailed steps? I cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/add-team-foundation-server.html), WebStorm only supports NTLM authentication or Alternate authentication:

[image]

Please try with NTLM authentication or Alternate authentication instead of PAT.